# Why do casting to (int?) work while (string?) doesnt in LINQ queries

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I'm writing a simple LINQ to XML query. As often, the some elements might be missing for some nodes in the XML document. To solve this issue, I tried to use nullable types and the coalesce operator as proposed by Scott Guthrie. Whan effect that I noticed is that casting elements to (string?) dit not work while casting to (int?) worked just fine. An example:

```
var modules = from module in XMLConfig.Descendants("module")
                          select new MyApp.Modules.Manager
                          {
                              ManagerUrl = (string?)module.Element("Manager") ?? "http://localhost/default.asmx",
                              ManagerType = (int?) module.Element("ManagerType") ?? 1,
                              ManagerNumber = (int?) module.Element("ManagerNumber") ?? 1,
                              PrinterNr = (int?) module.Element("PrinterNr") ?? 1,
                              TextNr = (int?) module.Element("TextNr") ?? 100,
                              Name = module.Element("Name").Value
                      };
```

This gave me the compiler error:

> Cannot convert type 'string?' to
>   'string'

However, there are no complaints when casting to (int?). If anyone could explain the reason for this behaviour (?) I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Thanx for all the answers. It is all clear to me now!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A string is a reference type, i.e. it is already "nullable". There is no need to wrap it in Nullable<T> as is required for value types which cannot be `null`.

This works:

```
ManagerUrl = (string)module.Element("Manager") ?? "http://localhost/default.asmx"
```

- `(string)module.Element("Manager")` returns null if the Manager element doesn't exist, and the contents of the element otherwise.
- `(int)module.Element("ManagerType")` would throw an exception if the ManagerType element doesn't exist, because a `int` cannot be null (value type).
- `(int?)module.Element("ManagerType")` does not throw an exception if the ManagerType element is missing, because a `int?` can be null (nullable type).

Answer (score 5):

This is because Nullable requires that T is a valuetype. `string` is a reference type, and is always nullable for that reason.

Answer (score 3):

String is a reference type, thus nullability is implcit. The ? modifier is for adding nullability to value types that don't already support it.